# undefined method `setup' for Config:Module (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config

I am getting above error while set up gem config in my application. The error only comes in production.

It is working fine on my local.

I am getting the error in `Config.setup do |config|`

**My Ruby version is 2.4 and rails version is 5.0**

I am using **Unicorn** as my application server

Error = `E, [2018-07-30T10:01:57.579983 #6128] ERROR -- : undefined method`setup' for Config:Module (NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the above problem by upgrading the Rails version from **5.0** to **Rails 5.1.6**

It was working on local because in my local machine **Rails 5.1** was already installed. It was a Rails versioning problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the source of gem to the latest location in your gemfile as below:

`gem 'config', github: 'railsconfig/config'`

Hope this helps !!!